# Android: Hex code vs @color/color_name

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set a color based on a style rather than a hex code but it's not working. All examples I've found seem to do it this way but it's not working for me. If I put the hex code in it works for the background color... still doesn't work for text color though.

`@color/kneeboard_blue` and `@color/btn_highlight`
I have a resource doc called `colors.xml` with this code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="kneeboard_blue">#4d6c96</color>
    <color name="btn_highlight">#c4c4c4</color>

</resources>
```

The styles.xml has this code in it:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/kneeboard_blue</item>
    <!--<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Text</item> -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_highlight</item>
</style>
```

Comment: the code should be ok. do you tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Yea, code should work. Where did you put your colors.xml file ? Make sure its in values folder.

Comment: It's in the same values folder as the styles.xml.  I tried quitting Android Studio and restarting and it worked... The title text didn't work but realized that I needed to create a style for AppTheme.ActionBar.Text.  Once I did that the color changed but the text size got a lot smaller. Now I'm trying to figure out what to do to call out the larger text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was a refresh issue with Android Studio. Once I quit and restarted AS it worked. They're still working out bugs I guess...